# Que tengo mal en el siguiente código, que me da advertencias

Tags: c, lenguaje-compilado

Resulta que debo crear un código donde presente un menú con 4 funciones del , que serían strcat, strcmp, strcpy y sctcmd, donde se debe ingresar la opción a elegir e ingresar cualquier carácter, pero me presenta un error, y quisiera que me ayudaran.

```
    #include <stdio.h>    
#include <string.h>
int concat (char a,char b)
{
strcat (a,b);
return 0;
}
int comparar (char a,char b)
{
strcmp (a,b);
return 0;
}
int copiar (char a,char b)
{
strcpy (a,b);
return 0;
}
int tama (char a)
{
strlen (a);
return 0;
}
int main (void)
{
int opcion,caracterp,caracters,resultado;
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    printf("operaciones de funciones de cadenas de caracteres\n");
    printf("|------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("| Elije una opcion                                     \n");
    printf("| 1.- Concatenar                                       \n");
    printf("| 2.- Comparar                                         \n");
    printf("| 3.- Copiar                                           \n");
    printf("| 4.- Tamaño                                           \n");
    printf("|------------------------------------------------------\n");
    scanf("%i",&opcion);
    switch (opcion)
    {
        case 1:
                    printf("- Concatenar -\n");
                    printf("Introduce el primer caracter");
                    scanf("%c",caracterp);
                    printf("introduce el segundo caracter");
                    scanf("%c",caracters);
                    resultado = concat(caracterp, caracters);
                    printf("Su resultado es", resultado);
                    break;
        case 2:
                    printf("- Comparar -\n");
                    printf("Introduce el primer caracter");
                    scanf("%c",caracterp);
                    printf("introduce el segundo caracter");
                    scanf("%c",caracters);
                    resultado = comparar(caracterp, caracters);
                    printf("Su resultado es", resultado);
                    break;
        case 3:
                    printf("- Copiar -\n");
                    printf("Introduce el primer caracter");
                    scanf("%c",caracterp);
                    printf("introduce el segundo caracter");
                    scanf("%c",caracters);
                    resultado = copiar(caracterp, caracters);
                    printf("Su resultado es", resultado);
                    break;
        case 4:
                    printf("- Tamaño -\n");
                    printf("Introduce el primer caracter");
                    scanf("%c",caracterp);
                    printf("introduce el segundo caracter");
                    scanf("%c",caracters);
                    resultado = tama(caracterp);
                    printf("Su resultado es", resultado);
                    break;
        default:
                     printf("Esa no es una opcion valida\n");
                     printf("%i no esta en el menu\n", opcion);
                     break;
                 }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Lo que tienes mal es lo que dice las advertencias. Como no puedo ver las advertencias no puedo saber qué tienes mal.

Answer (score 0):

soy un poco nuevo en esto pero creo saber dónde está el error, y es que le pasas los valores por referencia pero la función no retorna lo que quieres que retorne, es decir al llamar a

```
int comparar (char a,char b)
{
strcmp (a,b);
return 0;
}
```

Se reciben los valores y `strcmp` compara los caracteres y luego la función regresa 0, mientras que, para obtener el resultado correcto según lo que puedo ver en el program debería regresar el valor de esa comparación entonces debería quedar así:

```
int comparar (char a,char b)
{
res = strcmp (a,b);
return res;
}
```

Y eso estaría correcto pues una función de tipo entero regresa un valor de tipo entero que no es precisamente 0, sino el resultado de `strcmp(a,b)` (que es 0 cuando no hay diferencia entre los caracteres).

Ese sería el problema #1 que logro identificar. El #2 es el siguiente:

Todas las funciones las tienes como tipo `int` y algunas funciones que utilizas no retornan un entero:

- `strcat` me parece que retorna tipo `string`.
- `strcmp` retorna tipo `integer`.
- `strcpy` me parece retorna tipo `string`.
- `strlen` retorna tipo `integer`.

De igual forma, si cambias los valores de la función también lo haces con los de `printf(%c)`

### Completo C++

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <string>
#include <conio.h> //para getch() (que se cierre hasta apretar alguna tecla)
#include <iostream> // para cin y cout
std::string concat(char* a, char* b)
{
    return strcat(a, b);
}
int comparar(char* a, char* b)
{
    return strcmp(a, b);
}
std::string copiar(char* a, char* b)
{
    return strcpy(a, b);
}
int tama(char* a)
{
    return strlen(a);
}
int main(void)
{
    int opcion, resultado_entero;
    char caracterp[10] = { 0 }, caracters[10] = {0};
    std::string resultado_string;
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    printf("operaciones de funciones de cadenas de caracteres\n");
    printf("|------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("| Elije una opción                                     \n");
    printf("| 1.- Concatenar                                       \n");
    printf("| 2.- Comparar                                         \n");
    printf("| 3.- Copiar                                           \n");
    printf("| 4.- Tamaño                                           \n");
    printf("|------------------------------------------------------\n");
    scanf("%i", &opcion);
    switch (opcion) {
    case 1:
        printf("- Concatenar -\n");
        printf("Introduce el primer caracter");
        std::cin >> caracterp;
        std::cout << "\nIntroduce el segundo caracter: ";
        std::cin >> caracters;
        resultado_string = concat((char*)caracterp, (char*)caracters);
        std::cout << "\nResultado: " << resultado_string;
        getch();
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("- Comparar -\n");
        printf("Introduce el primer caracter");
        std::cin >> caracterp;
        std::cout << "\nIntroduce el segundo caracter: ";
        std::cin >> caracters;
        resultado_entero = comparar((char*)caracterp, (char*)caracters);
        std::cout << "\nResultado: " << resultado_entero;
        getch();
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("- Copiar -\n");
        printf("Introduce el primer caracter");
        std::cin >> caracterp;
        std::cout << "\nIntroduce el segundo caracter: ";
        std::cin >> caracters;
        resultado_string = copiar((char*)caracterp, (char*)caracters);
        std::cout << "\nResultado: " << resultado_string;
        getch();
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("- Tamaño -\n");
        printf("Introduce el caracter:");
        std::cin >> caracterp;
        resultado_entero = tama((char*)caracterp);
        std::cout << "\nResultado: " << resultado_entero;
        getch();
        break;
    default:
        printf("Esa no es una opcion valida\n");
        printf("%i no esta en el menu\n", opcion);
        break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Entendi un poco el primero problema, pero el segundo no, intento cambiar el codigo pero me sigue dando el mismo error de advertencia: passing argument 1 of "strcat" makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Con respecto a que si se que puedo ponerlo directamente, pero me lo pidieron llamarlo en una función.

Comment: Sí,por cierto, se me olvidó, no declares resultado como entero, sino hasta que sepas que es entero pues como mencioné antes, las funciones devuelven diferente tipo. Y el error es que strcat trabaja con punteros, con char* así que es probable sea ese el error.

Comment: Para que te podamos ayudar mejor, por favor específica más cuál es el problema pues puede haber una infinidad de problemas

Comment: Ya declaré los char* 
char* concat (char* as,char* bs)
{
 return strcat (as,bs);
}
pero me sigue diciendo lo mismo + assigment makes integer from pointer without a cast... La verdad me siento muy mal y la profesora que nos enseña es muy... como decirlo, desgraciada y disculpe la palabra, recien nos mandó a investigar que es un puntero y ya nos manda a meter eso en un ejercicio, y no entiendo lo que es nada.

Comment: Al momento de ejecutar el programa, me ejecuta normal mediante el Dev C++, pero al momento de ingresar los valores el programa no responde, mientras que en la compilación me salen esos errores
Line: 9 Col 1 [Warning] return makes pointer from integer without a cast,
(y con otros igual)

Comment: Line: 39, Col: 26 [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'concat' makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Comment: Oo rayos, ahora veo bien el código, tienes en main declaradas todas las variables como tipo entero, los carcateres son char y los enteros int, dame un segundo y hago en c++

Comment: Logró realizarlo?

Comment: Sí, ese código funciona bien para c++

Comment: Que extraño entonces porque no me funciona

Comment: ¿Qué error sale?

Comment: los que ya te comenté, esos warnings y al ejecutar el programa deja de responder al ingresar valores

Comment: Ok, prueba con el código que publiqué ayer, que está en mi respuesta que dice Completo C++, no le sé mucho a C y por eso está en C++, pero lo único sería cambiar unas pocas funciones para llevarlo a C, como cout o cin. El que deje de responder al ingresar valores quizá sea porque al tener scanf hay que limpiar el buffer con fflush(stdin) creo

Comment: Funcionó el código??

Comment: Mi problema estaba en no desarrollar bien en las funciones las opciones, lo hice de otra manera, pero tengo un problema en el strcpy, para ver si puedes ayudarme.

Comment: Está en la respuesta de arriba. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <string.h>

char concat ()
{
    char prim[100];
    char seg[100];
    printf ("Ingrese dos cadenas de caracteres a concatenar\n\n");
    scanf ("%s",prim);
    scanf ("%s",seg);
    strcat(prim,seg);
    printf ("\n %s \n",prim);
    return 0;   
}
char comp ()
{
    char pr[100];
    char sr[100];
    printf ("\n Ingrese dos cadenas de caracteres a comparar\n\n");
    scanf ("%s",pr);
    scanf ("%s",sr);
    int cond;
    cond= strcmp(pr,sr);
    if (cond<0||cond==1){
        printf ("\n Ambas Cadenas son diferentes");
    }
    else 
    if (cond==0){
        printf ("\n Ambas Cadenas son Iguales");
            }
    return 0;
}

char cantidad ()
{
    char can[100];
    int aux;
    printf ("\n Escriba una Palabra \n\n");
    scanf ("%s",can);
    aux=strlen(can);
    printf ("\n La cantidad de caracteres que posee son: %d",aux);
    return 0;
}

char copiar ()
{
    char cad1[30]="Usted es de :";
    char cad2[30];
    char cad3[30];
    printf (" \n En que ciudad vives? ");
    scanf ("%s",cad3);
    strcpy (cad2,cad1);
    strcpy (cad2+20,cad3);
    printf ("\n\n%s",cad2);
    return 0;       
}

int main(){
   int opc;
      printf("\n Elige una de las siguientes opciones\n");
      printf("\n 1.- Concatenar");
      printf("\n 2.- Comparar");
      printf("\n 3.- Cantidad de caracteres");
      printf("\n 4.- Copiar\n\n");
      scanf("%d",&opc);
      switch(opc){
         case 1: concat(); break;
         case 2: comp(); break;
         case 3: cantidad(); break;
         case 4: copiar(); break;
         default: printf(" \n Haz elegido una opción incorrecta\n\n");
      }
   return 0;
}
```